# How to create Multi Store in opencart Automatically?

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I have a project to build where I already developed a default Opencart store. There are multiple vendors in my store who can upload products from their admin panel. Every vendor has different admin panel.

What I want to do is on every vendor sign up a new multi store should be created automatically with different layouts & everything (with default theme & layout only) and registered vendor should have permissions to upload products on their own store & on default store only.

How can it be done?

Comment: Pardon me, this is a **site for programmers**. I didn't even read your question for two simple reasons joined in one sentence: **in your too long question I do not see any line of code**. This means that your question is *theoretical* which means it is either *Off Topic* or will attract *opinion-based* answers. BTW, welcome to Stackoverflow. **I recommend** reading the [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) first to find out how to ask good questions and what questions to avoid asking.

Comment: OK, after reading your question (and skipping the *what I already have* part - as this one is indisputably off topic and I'll remove it soon) I can definitely say that you question is *too broad* to be answered in one simple/single answer. Reading the help section (^^) will really help you to understand how things work here.

Comment: Could you please help me out for this ?

Comment: hey @shadyyx please help me out with this !!

Comment: Did you read the help section? If not, do it. If yes, do it two more times, pay enough attention. Your question is **too broad** to be answered here. And nobody here will put his effort for free to answer or do it for you.